# Build checkboxes with PHP from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have the following table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
  subject_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject text,
  PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

In the table I have already entered some data (subject names).

What I'm trying to do is that for each subject in the table, a checkbox is created with the name of the subject next to it.

So far I have managed to create checkboxes for each subject in the table, but I can not get the name of the subject shown next to the checkbox. Does anyone know how to do it?

I'm doing it this way:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT subject FROM subjects"; /*Select from table name: subjects*/
$result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/

if($result)
{
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='" . htmlspecialchars($row['subject']) . "' /> <label>Here goes the subject name</label>";
    }
}
?>
```

This is how my table looks like:

[image]

And this is what I'm getting in PHP:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the picture of the output...

Comment: try debugging the $row object, and see what it contains, using var_dump() or print_r() - you might be getting an object or array back from your query, rather than an associative array. you might only need to use $row[0]

Comment: How is it stored in the database?

Comment: Are you just looking for `echo "<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='" . htmlspecialchars($row['subject']) . "' /> <label>" . htmlspecialchars($row['subject']) 
 . "</label>";`

Comment: Why you set the name attribute to `data[]`

Comment: Your query is only selecting `subject`; is that the name? Should you maybe do a `SELECT *` and access `$row["subject_id"]` in `value` and just output `$row["subject"]` after?

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes!! This is it Chris, thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy actually, just concatenate the `$row['subject']` variable in between the label tags:

```
foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='" . htmlspecialchars($row['subject']) . "' /> <label>" .$row['subject'] . "</label>";
    }
```

You can use variables more than once in any output.

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you. It also works with <label>" . htmlspecialchars($row['subject']) . "</label>

Comment: Not sure why you're wrapping the values in that function - things coming from the database should be safe already.

Comment: No, you always escape for HTML output, never escape values before putting them in the database.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've always heard things should be stored in databases raw most of the time, and escaped on output.

Comment: escape on output is sufficient.